# How do you import 'process' in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Meteor currently advises to import everything. Like `import Meteor from 'meteor/meteor';`.

So if I want to do something like `console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL)`, what should I import?

Bonus question: I can't find the documentation for `process`, where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`process` is a global object (so no need for import) and only available on the server. It is part of the node environment.

See https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/process.html

Comment: ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooohhhhhhhhkay i thought it was a Meteor specific thing but it's actually a node thing. Thanks a bunch.